# ggvis interactivity in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis, choroplethr

I am trying to embed a ggvis plot in shiny with a hover element, but it seems that it doesn't render in shiny (the hover element that is). Below are the Server and UI components:

server.R:

```
library(choroplethrAdmin1)
library(choroplethr)
library(ggvis)
library(dplyr)

jor<-get_admin1_map("jordan")
jor$total <- runif(983) * 100


jor %>% ggvis(~long, ~lat) %>%
layer_paths(data = jor %>% group_by(name), 
          strokeWidth := 0, fill = ~total) %>%
hide_axis("x") %>% hide_axis("y") %>%
add_tooltip(function(data){paste("Gov: ", data$name, "<br>", "Total: ", as.character(data$lat))}, "hover")

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

jor%>%
ggvis(~long, ~lat) %>%
layer_paths(data = jor %>% group_by(name), 
          strokeWidth := 0, fill = ~total) %>%
hide_axis("x") %>% hide_axis("y") %>%
bind_shiny("p")
})
```

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(ggvis)

shinyUI(fluidPage(


titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),


mainPanel(
  ggvisOutput("p")
)
))
```

Is there something wrong in the code, or is that natural? It would be a real disappointment if the interactivity of ggvis is lost in shiny. If that is the case, are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding to shiny with `bind_shiny` with a `ggvis` plot that doesnt have the hover points. You do however have it above the `shinyServer` function. Just remove that, surplus to requirements anyway, and add the hover before the `bind_shiny` with the `shinyServer`.

server.R

```
library(choroplethrAdmin1)
library(choroplethr)
library(ggvis)
library(dplyr)

jor<-get_admin1_map("jordan")
jor$total <- runif(983) * 100

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  jor%>%
    ggvis(~long, ~lat) %>%
    layer_paths(data = jor %>% group_by(name), 
                strokeWidth := 0, fill = ~total) %>%
    hide_axis("x") %>% hide_axis("y") %>%
    add_tooltip(function(data){paste("Gov: ", data$name, "<br>", "Total: ",     as.character(data$lat))}, "hover") %>%
    bind_shiny("p")
})
```